# Fetch Data from REST API in mkdocs

Tags: python, mkdocs, mkdocs-macros

I am trying to create to port old wiki pages to a centralized location. Some of the data however needs to fetched in runtime from a REST Server.

For this purpose I have found a hacky solution of using *mkdocs-macros* plugin. And then create a custom module in the `main.py` file where I am using the python *requests* module to perform simple HTTP GET requests and return the required data.

Is there a better/proper way to do the above functionality in mkdocs?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of mkdocs-macros. Using macros would be actually, a "mkdoc-ic" way to develop your application. mkdocs-macros is listed in the [official catalog of mkdocs plugins](https://github.com/mkdocs/catalog#-code-execution-variables--templating), as a first choice in the category "Code execution, variables & templating".

If you want to call a REST API, you can indeed use a [Python module `main.py`](https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/macros/)and follow the standard pattern, as explained e.g. [on the Real Python page](https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/).

Something like:

```py
import requests

API_URL = "https://..."

def define_env(env):
    """
    This is the hook for the functions
    """

    @env.macro
    def uptime(machine_name: string) -> string:
        response = requests.get(f"{API_URL}?{machine_name}")
        fields = response.json()
        return fields['uptime']
```

Then you could use this call in your markdown page:

```markdown
At this moment the uptime of our server has been {{ uptime('foo') }}.
```

If you wish to build a reusable application that you can treat as a github projet, easily distribute and install (even through pypi), etc. I suggest to write it not as a module, but as a [pluglet](https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pluglets/).